# How can I put a CSV file in an array?

Tags: python, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array, python-2.x

I am reading a CSV file and I want to put it in an array so I can look up information quickly based on row index. This is what I got but it seems the row can't use split(). Any suggestions?

```
print csvFilePath
a = []

reader = csv.reader(open(csvFilePath,'rU'),dialect=csv.excel_tab)
print reader
for row in reader:
    print row
    a.append(row.split(','))

print a[45]['firstname']
```

Comment: what is `print a[45]['firstname']` supposed to be doing and what does your data look like? Also row is a list so it would make sense that you cannot split it

Comment: You don't appear to want to use arrays but rather lists.

Comment: You probably just want to do `a.append(row)`

Comment: Looks more like you want to put it into a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you most likely need is the `DictReader` (as bruno pointed out. He pulled the trigger faster.). It takes the file name and returns each row as a dictionary, which is want you want. This would make your code:

```
import csv
a = []

reader = csv.DictReader(open("so.csv",'rU'), dialect=csv.excel_tab, delimiter=',')
print reader
for row in reader:
    print row
    a.append(row)

print a[2]['Make']
```

Which optionally simplifies to:

```
import csv
with open("so.csv",'rU') as f:
    a = list(csv.DictReader(f, dialect=csv.excel_tab, delimiter=','))
print a[2]['Make']
```

Using some sample data (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Example)):

```
Year,Make,Model,Description,Price
1997,Ford,E350,"ac, abs, moon",3000.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition""","",4900.00
1999,Chevy,"Venture ""Extended Edition, Very Large""",,5000.00
1996,Jeep,Grand Cherokee,"MUST SELL!
air, moon roof, loaded",4799.00
```

Prints:

```
<csv.DictReader instance at 0x7fe7a3aedfc8>
{'Price': '3000.00', 'Description': 'ac, abs, moon', 'Make': 'Ford', 'Model': 'E350', 'Year': '1997'}
{'Price': '4900.00', 'Description': '', 'Make': 'Chevy', 'Model': 'Venture "Extended Edition"', 'Year': '1999'}
{'Price': '5000.00', 'Description': '', 'Make': 'Chevy', 'Model': 'Venture "Extended Edition, Very Large"', 'Year': '1999'}
{'Price': '4799.00', 'Description': 'MUST SELL!\nair, moon roof, loaded', 'Make': 'Jeep', 'Model': 'Grand Cherokee', 'Year': '1996'}
Chevy
```

This assumes that your file starts with a header like `Year,Make,Model,Description,Price`, to give the keys. If it does not, you can pass the header as a list to the `DictReader`:

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("so.csv",'rU'), ["Year", "Make", "Model", "Description", "Price"], dialect=csv.excel_tab, delimiter=',')
```

Also note that the spitting char is given by the `delimiter=','` argument.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the whole point of the `csv` module is to avoid parsing the csv file oneself, so no, `row` "can't use split" because it's already (correctly) "splitted" into a a list. If you want a list of your rows, then it's as simple as

```
with  open(csvFilePath,'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    a = list(reader)
```

Now if you want a list of dicts (so you can use `a[45]['firstname']`), you'll have to either use a `csv.DictReader()` instead (https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader), or build the dict from the row and a list of headers, ie:

```
headers = ["firstname", "lastname", "has_parrot",]
with  open(csvFilePath,'rU') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f), dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    a = [dict(zip(headers, row)) for row in reader]
```

but really using `csv.DictReader` is your better option.

Answer (score 0):

Python by default support two type of csv files, one is like this, comma separated:

```
1,2,3
```

the other one is like, tab separated:

```
1    2    3
```

or

```
 1\t2\t3
```

Now suppose you have these raw data:

```
 firstname,surname,..
 Adam,Smith,...
 ...
```

Now depending which type you had, you use this my mini wrapper library to get the two dimensional data that you would like to have:

```
 >>> import pyexcel as pe
 >>> sheet = pe.load("your_file.csv", name_columns_by_row=0) # or "your_file.tsv"
 >>> records = sheet.to_records()
 >>> records[45]["firstname"]
```

The detailed documentation is [here](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html)